# Calculating the area underneath a mathematical function

Tags: python, polynomial-math, numerical-integration

I have a range of data that I have approximated using a polynomial of degree 2 in Python. I want to calculate the area underneath this polynomial between 0 and 1.

Is there a calculus, or similar package from numpy that I can use, or should I just make a simple function to integrate these functions?

I'm a little unclear what the best approach for defining mathematical functions is.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a polynomial of degree 2, just integrate it by hand - there's no need to use code.

Comment: It's for a large set of polynomials, that I process in batches of 40.

Comment: The area under the curve of a polynomial of degree 2 is a polynomial with a degree of 1.  Just plug values into this equation.

Comment: @S.Lott It's degree 3, but yes.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: Ooops -- for some reason I was thinking of the derivative of  a polynomial at each point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're integrating only polynomials, you don't need to represent a general mathematical function, use `numpy.poly1d`, which has an `integ` method for integration.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> p = numpy.poly1d([2, 4, 6])
>>> print p
   2
2 x + 4 x + 6
>>> i = p.integ()
>>> i
poly1d([ 0.66666667,  2.        ,  6.        ,  0.        ])
>>> integrand = i(1) - i(0) # Use call notation to evaluate a poly1d
>>> integrand
8.6666666666666661
```

For integrating arbitrary numerical functions, you would use `scipy.integrate` with normal Python functions for functions. For integrating functions analytically, you would use `sympy`. It doesn't sound like you want either in this case, especially not the latter.

Comment: Great - thanks! That is very useful. So for calculating the area from 0 to 1, I can use: Area = i(1) - i(0) ?

Comment: That will be the definite integral from 0 to 1. In this case, that is the same as the area, but in some situations (where part or all of the polynomial is negative), it is not.

Answer (score 5):

Look, Ma, no imports!

```
>>> coeffs = [2., 4., 6.]
>>> sum(coeff / (i+1) for i, coeff in enumerate(reversed(coeffs)))
8.6666666666666661
>>>
```

Our guarantee: Works for a polynomial of any positive degree or your money back!

Update from our research lab: Guarantee extended; s/positive/non-negative/ :-)

**Update** Here's the industrial-strength version that is robust in the face of stray ints in the coefficients without having a function call in the loop, and uses neither `enumerate()` nor `reversed()` in the setup:

```
>>> icoeffs = [2, 4, 6]
>>> tot = 0.0
>>> divisor = float(len(icoeffs))
>>> for coeff in icoeffs:
...     tot += coeff / divisor
...     divisor -= 1.0
...
>>> tot
8.6666666666666661
>>>
```

Comment: +1, Good solution (practically the same as the one `integ` implements, I'm sure). I would make my denominator `float(i + 1)` if I wasn't in a file with `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 3):

It might be overkill to resort to general-purpose numeric integration algorithms for your special case...if you work out the algebra, there's a simple expression that gives you the area.

You have a polynomial of degree 2: **f(x) = ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c**

You want to find the area under the curve for **x** in the range **[0,1]**.

The antiderivative **F(x) = ax<sup>3</sup>/3 + bx<sup>2</sup>/2 + cx + C**

The area under the curve from 0 to 1 is: **F(1) - F(0) = a/3 + b/2 + c**

So if you're only calculating the area for the interval **[0,1]**, you might consider
using this simple expression rather than resorting to the general-purpose methods.

Answer (score 1):

'**quad**' in scipy.integrate is the general purpose method for integrating functions of a single variable over a definite interval. In a simple case (such as the one described in your question) you pass in your function and the lower and upper limits, respectively. 'quad' returns a tuple comprised of the integral result and an upper bound on the error term.

```
from scipy import integrate as TG

fnx = lambda x: 3*x**2 + 9*x    # some polynomial of degree two
aoc, err = TG.quad(fnx, 0, 1)
```

[Note: after i posted this i an answer posted before mine, and which represents polynomials using 'poly1d' in Numpy.  My scriptlet just above can also accept a polynomial in this form:

```
import numpy as NP

px = NP.poly1d([2,4,6])
aoc, err = TG.quad(px, 0, 1)
# returns (8.6666666666666661, 9.6219328800846896e-14)
```

Comment: Since polynomials can be analytically integrated trivially, it is best to use the more-efficient `integ` method rather than repeated Gauss quadrature for them.

Answer (score 1):

If one is integrating quadratic or cubic polynomials from the get-go, an alternative to deriving the explicit integral expressions is to use Simpson's rule; it is a deep fact that this method *exactly* integrates polynomials of degree 3 and lower.

To borrow Mike Graham's example (I haven't used Python in a while; apologies if the code looks wonky):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> p = numpy.poly1d([2, 4, 6])
>>> print p
   2
2 x + 4 x + 6
>>> integrand = (1 - 0)(p(0) + 4*p((0 + 1)/2) + p(1))/6
```

uses Simpson's rule to compute the value of `integrand`. You can verify for yourself that the method works as advertised.

Of course, I did not simplify the expression for `integrand` to indicate that the `0` and `1` can be replaced with arbitrary values `u` and `v`, and the code will still work for finding the integral of the function from `u` to `v`.

Comment: What a nice answer! Simpson's rule, tried and true, from calculus. Very elegant, regardless of Python skills.